# Processing group policy with GP Extension

Tags: c, windows, group-policy

I created a Group Policy extension that implements ProcessGroupPolicyEx.
I sucesfully am notified when I receive a group policy.

I am however at a loss to how to read the policy from inside the GPO. The [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373494(v=vs.85).aspx) stops at looping through GPOs:

```
 for( pCurGPO = pChangedGPOList; pCurGPO; pCurGPO = pCurGPO->pNext )
   {
       if( *pbAbort )
       {
           // Abort.
           break;
       }
       // ...
   }
```

That is fine, but how do I get the policy (the actual settings) inside the pCurGPO? I need to get either the settings that this GPO contains, or the registry key where it stores them.  This is because I created multiple ADMX templates that target my extension, so I need to tell them apart.

So far, I've found some samples, but they assume that the extension knows what registries will be changed, in advance. However, in my case, I do not want the extension to make this assumption, I want it to check the updated GPO and determine exactly what is being changed.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if the ask is how to parse GPO struct https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374173(v=vs.85).aspx why isn't this helpful? Aah I misread it. You're well past that.

Comment: That tells  me how to get information about the goo. However I cannot get information about what the GPO contains. For example, in my extension, I want to check if the GOP modified a particular subkey.

Comment: Yes I understand in my current setup I don't have an ability to help you with this one directly, but chrome has a bit of code that parses and figures out Group policy you can have a look? https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/27658f3df0e55b6fb89ec56c2751f46fbc86a5ab/chrome/browser/policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after squirreling through the Chromium code (per amritanshu comment), I found one way which seems to work, however I am not yet understanding what exceptions there may be (if any):

1. get lpFileSysPath field of the pCurObj which will be a UNC path.
2. Append "\Registry.pol" to the path.
3. Read and parse the resulting file, which will be a PReg file.

The PReg file is documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374407(v=vs.85).aspx

If anyone sees anything wrong with this approach, or knows of any exceptions for this algorithm, please let me know.

EDIT:
Also found this blog with a better written, though similar explanation: https://redsigil.weebly.com/home/group-policy-callbacks-the-missing-documentation